# Drawing shapes in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to put a border around an image in GIMP. I've drawn the shape, using the rectangle tool, I've selected the stroke, and can see the shape in the correct size and all. But it still has the marching ants, and I no matter what I do, I can't save it or get it to stay there. I've read lots of answers to similar questions, but they all end at "stroke selection". I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I am stumped and hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your selection, you can use "[Stroke Selection](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-stroke.html)" to paint the borders using a [Stroke Style](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-path-stroke.html). You can use either a solid color, a pattern or a paint tool (e.g. Paintbrush). Before pressing "Stroke" you should set up the selected color, pattern or tool respectively.

Cf. https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Borders_On_Selections/